# Overriding z-index with button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #div1
            {
                position:absolute;
                left:0px;
                top:0px;
                z-index:-1;
                width:100px;
                height:100px;
                background-color:#F00;
            }
            #div2
            {
                position:absolute;
                left:0px;
                top:0px;
                z-index:-1;
                width:100px;
                height:100px;
                background-color:#000;
            }
            #div3
            {
                position:absolute;
                left:0px;
                top:0px;
                z-index:-1;
                width:100px;
                height:100px;
                background-color:#ccc;
            }
            #div4
            {
                position:absolute;
                left:0px;
                top:0px;
                z-index:-1;
                width:100px;
                height:100px;
                background-color:#999;
            }
            #links
            {
                position:absolute;
                left:0px;
                top:200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1">Div 1</div>
        <div id="div2">Div 2</div>
        <div id="div3">Div 3</div>
        <div id="div4">Div 4</div>

        <div id="links">
            <input type="button" value="Link1" onclick="resetAll(); up('div1');">
            <input type="button" value="Link2" onclick="resetAll(); up('div2');">
            <input type="button" value="Link3" onclick="resetAll(); up('div3');">
            <input type="button" value="Link4" onclick="resetAll(); up('div4');">

            <script>
                function reset(id)
                {
                    document.getElementById(id).style.zIndex = 1000;
                }

                function up(element)
                {
                    element.style.zIndex = 1;
                }

                function resetAll()
                {
                    for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
                    {
                        reset('div' + i);
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So that works, when you click `Link 2` button to display `div2`, it overrides the `zindex` of `div1` just fine, as I'd like.

However, when you click `Link 1` (which is supposed to display `div1`), it doesn't go back to `div1`. I'd like whichever button I click to display the div it is linked to.

Comment: Call a function on the button click, rather than writing inline script. Pass the function the div ID. Set all the div's to have zIndex -1 (use a class selector), then set the one associated with the button to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should reset **all** your divs to their original state... then mark your selected. do..upgrade your html to this version:

```
<div id="div1">Div 1</div>
<div id="div2">Div 2</div>
<div id="div3">Div 3</div>
<div id="div4">Div 4</div>

<div id="links">
<input type="button" value="Link1" onclick="resetAll(); up('div1');">
<input type="button" value="Link2" onclick="resetAll(); up('div2');">
<input type="button" value="Link3" onclick="resetAll(); up('div3');">
<input type="button" value="Link4" onclick="resetAll(); up('div4');">
</div>
```

and add this JS functions:

```
function reset(id)
{
    document.getElementById(id).style.zIndex = 1000;
}

function up(element)
{
    element.style.zIndex = 1;
}

function resetAll()
{
    for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        reset('div' + i);
    }
}
```

and here comes the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ymzrocks/5604wmtc/

Comment: I've altered my original post to match your suggestions...but I still can't make it work. Any other advice?

Comment: copy and paste from fiddle.. the functions should be located inside your script tag

Comment: Fantastic yackov, this works. Thanks mate, marking as correct now. Thanks to everyone for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the first one back to 0

```
<script>

var shown;
function show(){
    if(shown) shown.style.zIndex = 0;
    shown = this;
    shown.style.zIndex = 1;
}

</script>
```

then

```
<input type="button" value="Link1" onclick="show()">
<input type="button" value="Link2" onclick="show()">
<input type="button" value="Link3" onclick="show()">
<input type="button" value="Link4" onclick="show()">
```

Answer (score 0):

it is the correct behavior because step by step you are giving `z-index=1` to all divs. Id div4 is visible with `z-index=1` and you execute `document.getElementById('div1').style.zIndex='1'` the correct behavior is show div4. You should give an higher z-index to div1 or a lower z-index to other divs